# formula pago / pmt en excel devuelve un valor no igual al excel usando js

Tags: javascript, excel, formulas

la formula excel es la siguiente

```
// Excel
    =REDONDEAR((-PAGO($F$7;$F$8;$F$6;0;0)+I21);0)
```

los valores en las celdas excel

```
 //excel
$F$7 = 1.92%  //porcentaje 
$F$8 = 12       //meses
$F$6 = 1000000   //monto
I21 = "" //vacio, no hay nada
```

mi codigo js es el siguiente

```
// JS
var dato = 25.60;

var calculoDecimal = (((dato/100 + 1)**0.0833333333333333)) - 1;

var calculoPorcentaje = calculoDecimal * 100;

// Redondeamos a 2 decimales
//console.log(calculoPorcentaje.toFixed(2) + " %")
console.log(calculoPorcentaje.toFixed(2)/100);
var rate = calculoPorcentaje.toFixed(2)/100;

var periods = 12
var present = 1000000
var future = null
var type= null



function PMT( rate , periods, present, future, type) {
  // Credits: algorithm inspired by Apache OpenOffice

  // Initialize type
  var type = (typeof type === 'undefined') ? 0 : type;

  // Evaluate rate (TODO: replace with secure expression evaluator)
  rate = eval(rate);

  // Return payment
  var result;
  if (rate === 0) {
    result = (present + future) / periods;
  } else {
    var term = Math.pow(1 + rate, periods);
    if (type === 1) {
      result = Math.round((future * rate / (term - 1) + present * rate / (1 - 1 / term)) / (1 + rate));
    } else {
      result = Math.round( future * rate / (term - 1) + present * rate / (1 - 1 / term));
    }
  }
  return -result;
}
```

obtengo en la consola al ejecutar la funcion

```
PMT( rate , periods, present, future, type)
-94096
```

pero en mi documento de excel ese campo [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

tengo entendido que el 0 del final de la formula que genera los datos en excel
se usa para lo siguiente :
Con Tipo = 0, el interés se calcula durante 1 mes porque se supone que el pago es al final del mes. Para Tipo = 1, el interés se calcula por 0 meses porque el pago es al comienzo del mes.

Comment: El último argumento de la fórmula PAGO solo indica si el vencimiento es al inicio del período o al final. Por poner un ejemplo sencillo, en España los vencimientos de alquileres son al principio (se pagan al principio del mes que vas a vivir) pero la nómina de un trabajador se paga a final de mes, cuando ya ha trabajado. Es un ejemplo burdo pero van por ahí los tiros. Pero independientemente de eso es 0 o 1 se seguirá calculando en meses o la unidad que le corresponda.

Comment: **Tenia el mismo problema.**
Lo que hice fue eliminar el signo negativo, pero igualmente la cifra difiere con el excel por decimas. *return result;* Como no era mucha diferencia opte por dejarlo así.